# Customizing <div> borders using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, layout

I am trying to create a web page that looks like like in this site:

[image]

I tried creating an image with that design(the one in the middle with a white background and pointy edges on the top and bottom) but the result is that the image is static and does not dynamically change when the content of the page changes.

I do not know if I can implement the design by customizing the `<div>` borders or upload the design as a background image then dynamically create it.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: see this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774952/making-jagged-triangle-border-in-css)

Comment: I can't access the image!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use CSS3 (for more browser support) use the following structure:

```
<div class="conatiner">
    <div class="pointyHeader"></div>
    <div class="content">
         your dynamic content here
    </div>
    <div class="pointyFooter"></div>
</div>
```

where `pointyHeader` and `pointyFooter` have a fixed height and background image.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9huxt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a `.box { position: relative; }`
and a `.top { position: absolute; top: 0; }` and same with bottom `.bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 0;}`

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DyG8F/