# How do I style a different border?

Tags: css

how can I style a border differently then solid/dotted etc.?
I do have a zigzag-line as a border-top and of course I can display it as a graphic-file within the background, but is there a different (more modern) way to achieve that?

I am asking this specifically for a zigzag-line for one border (border-top) AND for any other scenario, where a different looking border shall be used (rotated solid borders....)

How would I do something like this?

- ::before
- css-shapes
- still with graphic-files

It should work down to IE9

Thanks

Comment: Your question is close enough to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774952/making-jagged-triangle-border-in-css but that wouldn't work with IE9. I think it would be better for you to use SVG (even `border-image` won't work in IE10-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this codePen example:

http://codepen.io/pouretrebelle/pen/hypGk

```css
.bordered {
  background-color: #efe6ef;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: 5em;
  width: 25em;
}

.bordered:before, .bordered:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bordered:before {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb);
  background-position: 0.5em 0.5em, 0.5em 0.5em, 0 0.5em, 0 0.5em;
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  left: 0;
  top: -1em;
  height: 7em;
  width: 100%;
}

.bordered:after {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'), url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -moz-linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -webkit-linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), linear-gradient(315deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75%, #b6b5eb 75%, #b6b5eb);
  background-position: 0.5em 0.5em, 0.5em 0em, 0.5em 0, 0.5em 0.5em;
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  left: -1em;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 27em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: Quando, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">
  <h1>CSS Zigzag Border</h1>
</div>
```