# How to make CSS zig-zag borders?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to  get this effect along the baseline of my header element.

[image]

What is the best way to go about it? Is there any way to do it without images (maybe SVG)?

A way I reckon this could be accomplished pretty nicely is using a repeat-x background image of a white square on an absolutely positioned pseudo element. However, that uses images and I'd love to be able to avoid that.

Comment: check out this post - looks like they solved it over there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774952/making-jagged-triangle-border-in-css

Comment: an online generator for this and more: https://css-generators.com/custom-borders/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is solution. It's called zig-zag border.

http://jsfiddle.net/justinmc/QqnD3/

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Content Here</h1>
</div>

.container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 8px 32px 8px;
    background: #dddccf;
}

.container:after {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0), linear-gradient(45deg, #ffffff 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

credits
https://cocreate.localmotors.com/blog/post/zig-zag-borders-in-css/1205/