# create a triangular border pattern

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create in CSS a border pattern to apply on the top and bottom of my content. It should look like this (the teeth should be black):

```
+--------------------+
|\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/|
|                    |
|  the actual        |
|         content    |
|/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|
---------------------+
```

I am trying to make the teeth black and the rest of the border area transparent.
My main idea is to work with `background-image` and `linear-gradient`.

I have managed to draw the left half of a black tooth with:

```
linear-gradient(45deg, white 0 50%, black 50% 100%)
```

... and the right half with:

```
linear-gradient(135deg, black 0 50%, white 50% 100%)
```

The plan is the to put the two halves side-by-side and then simply use `background-repeat: repeat-x` to paint as many teeth as are necessary for the width. That would allow me to do the top row of the teeth and then I would do the bottom row in a similar manner.

The plan fails because I cannot stack the two parts of the tooth horizontally, side by side.

Online playground is [here](https://playcode.io/1106257). Can you help me finish the top row of teeth?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774952/making-jagged-triangle-border-in-css

Comment: https://css-generators.com/custom-borders/