# How to put fancy border around an image in html5?

Tags: html, image, google-chrome

I am making an `html` page in which I have put some pictures. Now I want to put some fancy borders around it. How do I do that? My code is:

```
<img src="award.gif">
```

When I run it, it comes out perfectly. But I need a border. I use the latest version of Google Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean fancy? It totally depends on what you or your client wants.

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/css/4-fun-css-image-effects-you-can-copy-and-paste/

Comment: https://fatpony.me/csstutorial/fancy-css-borders-images-border-radius/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS rules to set border around the image, see the below link where you can see different CSS borders and you can generate cross-browser border CSS. I like this tool very much and this tool provides an intuitive preview to see how the border will look like-

http://www.cssmatic.com/border-radius

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/css/4-fun-css-image-effects-you-can-copy-and-paste/

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

**css:**

```
img { 
   border:1px solid #021a40;
}
```

The "Double Border":

```
img {
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
}
```

For multiple images, you can class in each images, and css is here,

Simple [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2akp8cfp/)

Another one [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n7fmtm2v/)

And for more about border and border-radius refer this [Link](https://fatpony.me/csstutorial/fancy-css-borders-images-border-radius/)

**UPDATE:**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zjafeL9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a  instead  because in matters of CSS this can be more versatile.

CSS

```
myImage { 
    background:url(path to image file goes here);
    border: 1px solid #000000; //black border
    //some width and height values
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="myImage"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to figure what he meant by fancy

Comment: I meant something good looking, attractive, etc. Basically something which improves the quality of the page

Comment: In that case its not about the property, its about the design. Remember that a website is going to look fancy not because the use of css properties, but an adequate management of your design. Sometimes even not using border radius but shadowing properties makes attractive sites, but as im saying, it all depends on the concept and your needs.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="divimg">
<img src="award.gif">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divimg {
 border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: @JitendraPancholi thanks for letting me know that he need fancy edge borders then user identicon check this link which I have answered for geting fancy jagged edges, hope this is fancy  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972888/make-a-divs-top-and-bottom-border-have-a-jagged-edge

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing that, you can create a div and put the image inside the div and then, with css, create the border.
Another simple way is this:

```css
img {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:red;
  }
```