# How to implement a repeating SVG at the top and bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, svg, web-frontend

I'm working on site where I put something in a design I'm having a bit of trouble with.  I put a repeating triangle pattern at the top and bottom of a div and this throwing me for a little bit of a loop.

You see a lot of sites with SVG's at the top and bottom and I've noticed that a lot of them are a single contiguous shape, such as a long wave, or a single slant but in this case I'd like to have a single triangle that's approximately 150px high and 75px wide as the base shape and have it repeat horizontally to fill the width of the containing element (let's say a div) and be anchored to the top and/or bottom.

[image: horizontally repeating SVG]

I'm not sure how to approach this and am in search of suggestion for how to implement this on a website.

Comment: Just a note, I know how to create SVGs in Adobe Illustrator and extract their code.

Comment: if it's about a trianlge, you don't need SVG.

Comment: You've closed this as there's another answer, but it uses a pseudo-element. If you want a cleaner way, how about this?

body {
 margin:0;
 min-height:100vh;
 background-color:#005b79;
 background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='150' height='75' fill='white'><polygon points='0,0 75,75 150,0' /></svg>"), url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='150' height='75' fill='white'><polygon points='0,75 75,0 150,75' /></svg>");
 background-repeat:repeat-x, repeat-x;
 background-position:top, bottom;
}

Comment: It was closed by someone else and marked as a duplicate.  The duplicate answer helped me find what I needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031328/css-zigzag-border-with-a-textured-background

This was also helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container